# How to save state of multiple checkboxes to the backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I have multiple checkboxes e.g. 50 in my SPA that I show on one of the views. The user can select/unselect any number of checkboxes and then click on save.

1. Send http request on every change on checkbox
2. Send all the data bound to checkboxes on save regardless of whether user changed something or not
3. Send only the changed data bound to checkboxes (dirty checking? diffing on save?)

Comment: What do you need help with? Please provide the code you have written so far.

Comment: That is the whole point of the question. I want to know the right way to do it. So that I dont waste time writing code only to refactor it later.